# How to filter object based on if property is available in AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, user-interface

I'd like to only return results with the 'Company Name' property not == null.  All results with 'Company Name == N/A will not be displayed.

```
<li><input class="form-control  fInput" data-ng-model="search.CompanyName"></li>



 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 main">
        <div ng-if="isEditMode == false" class="col-lg-4" ng-class="{'active':isSelectedContact(contact.ContactId)}" ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:{Category:{CategoryId:currentCategory.CategoryId}}  
                                                                                                                                                    | filter: search.CompanyName
                                                                                                                                                    | orderBy: ['LastName','FirstName'] ">



            <div class="img-rounded contactBoxes">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs smBtn" title="Delete Contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="editContact(contact)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs smBtn" title="Edit Contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                {{contact.FirstName}} {{contact.MiddleName}} {{contact.LastName}}<br />
                Company: {{contact.CompanyName || "N/A"}}<br />
                Email: <a href="mailto:{{contact.Email}}">{{contact.Email}}</a><br />
                Cell: {{contact.CellPhone}}<br />
                Work: {{contact.WorkPhone || "N/A"}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not render results with null CompanyName, a simple `ng-if` condition should suffice:

```
<div ng-if="isEditMode == false && contact.CompanyName != null" class="col-lg-4"
    ng-class="{'active':isSelectedContact(contact.ContactId)}"
    ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:{Category: {CategoryId:currentCategory.CategoryId}} | filter: search.CompanyName | orderBy: ['LastName','FirstName']">

...

</div>
```

Comment: I get 'ng-if already exists'.  It compiles but the it still returns results with null Company Name.

Comment: this works but I want it to work for a search field.  Only display search results of contacts containing a Company Name.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ng-show` it will check if contact.CompanyName is not null

```
<div class="img-rounded contactBoxes"  ng-show="contact.CompanyName != null">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs smBtn" title="Delete Contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="editContact(contact)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs smBtn" title="Edit Contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                {{contact.FirstName}} {{contact.MiddleName}} {{contact.LastName}}<br />
                Company: {{contact.CompanyName || "N/A"}}<br />
                Email: <a href="mailto:{{contact.Email}}">{{contact.Email}}</a><br />
                Cell: {{contact.CellPhone}}<br />
                Work: {{contact.WorkPhone || "N/A"}}

</div>
```

Comment: This almost works.  When the user enters text into the textbox labeled “Company Filter”, only
contacts whose Company property contains the text entered should be displayed.